# How to structure a MYSQL table with lots of data?

Tags: mysql

I have statistics for every user in our system. These statistics need to be updated frequently.

The statistics looks something like this:

```
Campaign : Performance
Campaign : Performance
```

Each campaign has it's own data stored in another table in MYSQL. The performance metric needs to be updated for each user and each campaign frequently. There are over 1000 campaigns that need to be updated for over 5000 users.

At first I considered simply making a huge VARCHAR column which just stored the data as "campaignId-Performance,campaignId2-Performance,..."

When querying the DB these campaigns will be searched for by their COUNTRY first and then ordered in descending order by the highest performing. The COUNTRY data is stored in the campaigns table. In my new table I was considering making a column for every COUNTRY and splitting the campaigns with their respective performances up like that. I'm unsure whether that would be more efficient or not.

With this poor description I'm hoping someone can suggest an optimal structure. Thanks!

Comment: Are you just wanting a new table that would de-normalize information already in other tables?

Comment: Nope - the performance data is not currently stored in the database.

Comment: If you meant that you were thinking about splitting it into a different table for each country, then consider [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) the table on the country column instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you would want to store this performance in a table with 3 columns: `campaignID,userID,performance`. This would give you the most flexibility to then query the information however you might need it. Would easily aggregate performance by campaign, or by user. and with a quick join to the campaign table would allow you to aggregate by country as well.

Comment: This would create 5000*1000 rows. Is that more efficient to search through?

Comment: More efficient than what? Properly indexed the rowcount isn't really going to be that big of a factor. It's definitely going to be more efficient than your "huge VARCHAR column" with the comma delimited list when you need a specific campaign's performance for a user or need to roll-up performance for the campaign for all users since you won't need to parse through the text string to find your data, you'll just have it there to query.

Comment: You're welcome. It's vital to get these early data designs planned correctly. As making small missteps early in the design tend to escalate into huge growing pains later. Considering hiring a specialist or consultant to assist you, if needed. You'll thank yourself five years down the road.

Answer (score 0):

So, your building a MySQL database that contains 1000 campaigns and 5000 users? Do the campaigns contain the performances of each country?  If so, I would suggest making a column named Country followed by Performance Column.  Also, it would be helpful to know what your trying to view the information in.

Comment: Each user has data on these 1000 campaigns, but the performance of the campaign for each user is different. Each campaign also can only be run in certain countries. This information is available in my campaigns table. The MYSQL queries will be in made in PHP - I'm not sure if that's what you were asking?

Comment: Well i'm not very familiar with PHP, However if you Visual Studio .Net you can connect the program to MySQL.  Visual Studio will pull all of your data from your MySql database and allow you to manage it the way you like.  If this doesn't help you than I am sorry. :/